# Linking hierarchically two listBoxes with dictionaries as their sources

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox

I hope I'l explain it well :)

I have .txt files which are in folders I load into a program. I process the data in the files and put it in lists, then I put the lists in one dictionary that represents one .txt file. Then i put those dictionaries in another dictionary that represents the folder. Everything has its own keys.

Then I have two listboxes and a textbox. the first one loads the keys from the "master" dictionary.

The problem: When I click on the listbox items, I would like to display values of the Master dictionary on the second listbox. When I click on the second listbox, I'd like the textbox to display the data that corresponds to values of the secondary dictionary.

the master dictionary looks like:

```
glavniKodeks <string, Dictionary<string, List(Entry>>>
```

the secondary dictionary looks like:

```
kodeks<string>, List<Entry>>.
```

the Entry is a class that creates and puts the data into list.

```
 listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(glavniKodeks.Keys, null);
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";

    public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // (when i click on the items in the listbox1, the values from
      // the master dictionary, which are the keys of a secondary
      // dictionary, should display on the second listbox2)
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // (when I click on the items selected here, the secondary's 
      //  dictionary values should be extracted from the dictionary into
      //  a array, which I can  manipulate further with.)
    }
```

Is such thing even possible? I've been scouring the net with similar solutions but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Instead of posting the solution as an edit to your question, post the solution as answer.

Comment: It's more readable and useful if you load data in a `List<Master>`  which `Master` has a `Name` and a `List<Detail>` while `Detail` has a `Name` and a `List<Entry>`. This way you can perform data-binding simply using configurations without writing code to extract details from selected master.

Comment: @reza Thx for the answer tip, not a frequent user. Regarding the other question, I am working with 10k -ish txt files hierarhically stacked in the manner explained, friend suggested a dictionary approach would be more optimized since i'm going for performance. But again, just a novice here, so I'll try your approach.

Comment: Dictionary is much faster than list for lookup You should check if lookup time is important for your application or not. [Dictionary vs List Lookup Time](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time)

Comment: Yes it's the case here, my dictionary has about 27k key value pairs, each of those pairs is a dictionary with another 7/14 pairs , and each of those values is a list with 200 entries. I needed to get to those entries as fast as possible, so I guess i'm better off with dictionaries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

messed with the code and found this :)

```
public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        var odabrano1 = glavniKodeks.Keys.ToList()[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        glavniKodeks.TryGetValue(odabrano1, out kodeks);
        listBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(kodeks.Keys, null);
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<Entry>();
        var odabrano2 = kodeks.Keys.ToList()[listBox2.SelectedIndex];
        kodeks.TryGetValue(odabrano2, out list);
    }
```

now I have a extracted List list, which I can manipulate :)